# How to pass string and images data from one Activity to another Activity in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Hi I am very new for android and in my project I have created one list-view in my MainActivity and when I click on List-view row I want to show that details on my DetailActivity(here I want to display userimage, name, desc).

For this I have written below code but when I click on ListView row exception is coming like(NullPointerException). What did I do here wrong?

### MainActivity:-

```
String[] nameArray;
String[] descArray;
int[] images;

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Intent detail=new Intent(MainActivity.this,DetailActivity.class);
    detail.putExtra("titles",nameArray[position]);
    detail.putExtra("description", descArray[position]);
    detail.putExtra("images",images[position]);
    startActivity(detail);
}
```

### DetailActivity:-

```
ImageView Image;
TextView Name;
TextView Desc;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    Name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Desc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String name = bundle.getString("titles");
    String desc = bundle.getString("description");
    String image = bundle.getString("images");

    Image.setImageResource(image);
    Name.setText(name);
    Desc.setText(desc);
}
```

Comment: why don't you use getters and setters?

Comment: Where do you have the images? in drawables ? I am assuming that the arrays are charged , aren´t they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are not attaching xml in onCreate method in detailActivity

like this

setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash_board_main);

Comment: and one more thing u will get again exception , you are passing integer value here detail.putExtra("images",images[position]); and u are reading as a String in Detail Activity

Comment: i think u will get one more exception, you cann't set image by passing String in this method Image.setImageResource(image);